# Magento 2 How can I create a custom api to delete your customer account (profile account)?

Tags: php, react-native, magento2

I need help to check if the customer I want to delete is my customer (based on access token - authorization Bearer ...). I send in endpoint the customer_id (/customer-delete/:customer_id) and in Headers I have Authorization token for customer. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-api/

Answer (score 0):

API to delete customer account already exist: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.delete.html

Comment: Exist, but this API is for admin.. only admins can delete the account.. if you want to delete your account from a mobile app you need to create a custom api.. i found the solution for decoding customer authentification token and get the customer data.. thank you